# Vista: Switching users or logging off sometimes hangs forever

Tags: windows-vista

I'm seeing a hang on Windows Vista Home Premium. When I switch users or log off, it goes back out to the "Please Wait" screen - usually after 1/2 a second it gives the main login screen, but sometimes it hangs forever.

Since I don't have access to the task manager, I have no choice but to do a hard reboot. Once the system comes back up, there's nothing in the system log indicating any problems.

The system has all the latest patches installed as well as AVG anti-virus. It doesn't happen every time, and I've tried shutting down all applications before logging off, but it doesn't seem to help. Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to determine what the problem is, given that I have no access to the task manager or anything else when it happens?

*Update*: I posted this question and then promptly forgot about it. I was reminded when I was awarded the [Tumbleweed badge](https://superuser.com/badges/38/tumbleweed), so I cleaned it up in the hopes that a better written question might get more notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled AVG anti-virus, and the problem went away.